# Managing links in OpenScholar

Tags: php, drupal

I would like to move around the links included in a menu containing links in an OpenScholar website. According to the OpenScholar documentation it is possible to move items within the [menu control panel](http://support.openscholar.harvard.edu/customer/portal/articles/1215225-manage-menus). This appears not to be possible to manage a list of links to external websites included in the links app. Is there another option for sorting the lnks in this app apart from deleting all of them and importing a new `csv` file containing the ordered links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by the openscholar support team at my institute. The only way to sort the links inside the links app is to hover over each link and click on the Edit button. Then on right hand side of the pop-up window, click on Authoring Information to change the date to an older date. After saving changes the link ordering will be modified. The links with the most recent date will be on top of the list.